# twentytwenty children theme, using gutenberg, changing a title change them all

Tags: block-editor, child-theme, title

I started to look forward modifying thèmes and i made a children theme from twentytwenty. On the landing page, using gutenberg, i edited page name at top, then added some paragraph, gallery and when time came for a H2 ( labeled as in the block ) writing something change also the page name. It occur also when i put a h3 title. i dont have a clue on what's happen here. Any tips welcome.

here is a copy of what the H1 and H2 under the page title look like on inspector

```
<h1 contenteditable="true" class="wp-block wp-block-post-title block-editor-block-list__block editor-post-title editor-post-title__input rich-text" aria-label="Add title" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" style="white-space: pre-wrap; min-width: 1px;">BricoTips</h1>
<h2 role="document" aria-multiline="true" aria-label="Block: Title" class="block-editor-rich-text__editable block-editor-block-list__block wp-block has-text-align-center wp-block-post-title rich-text" id="block-aba9fa93-4e8b-4424-a932-88d02d829313" data-block="aba9fa93-4e8b-4424-a932-88d02d829313" data-type="core/post-title" data-title="Title" contenteditable="true" style="white-space: pre-wrap; min-width: 1px;">BricoTips</h2>
```

here is a copy of the styles.css from the child thème:

```css
/*
Theme Name:   BricoTips
Theme URI:    http://bricotips.local/
Description:  Thème BricoTips basé sur le thème TwentyTwenty
Author:       Mr Brico
Author URI:   https://lacouralexandre.tech
Template:     twentytwenty
Version:      1.0.0
License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags:         bricolage, outils, lexique
Text Domain:  brico-tips
*/
@import url(../twentytwenty/style.css);
```

[image: files tree]

and the functions.php :

```php
<?php

function theme_enqueue_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles');}
```

with child theme on :

[image: child-theme on]

with parent theme active :

[image: parent-theme on]

let me know if you need any more infos

thanks for helping out !

Comment: are you sure it's 2020 theme that you've made a child theme out of? Block themes weren't a thing when 2020 was released, are you sure you don't mean 2023 or 2024? Can you include screenshots? It's not 100% clear what the process you took was, and the HTML from inside the block editor isn't very useful for this

Comment: Edited and added requested infos

Comment: and , i ve same problem when i m modifying thing in the parent theme. going to delete all theme , and redo it all.

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

Making child theme pulled on top of the page i was modifying a post-type component, in that component all the titles will have the same value. While reinstalling the project, i suppressed the posts before making the child theme, and now i can modify my page without this conflict.

Also, i modified the version in my style.css of the parent-theme, it fixed the css import and i dont need the import line in style.css anymore :)

Thanks for the reply !

edit: and no it didnt fixed anything, seem title is an object in that theme, so i used headings and now it seem to work :s